# Convert ANN_MLP code in OpenCV 2 to OpenCV 3 code

Tags: c++, opencv

My code in OpenCV 2 is:

```
ann.create(layers, CvANN_MLP::SIGMOID_SYM, 1, 1);
```

How to convert it to OpenCV 3? When I convert `CvANN_MLP` to `cv::ml::ANN_MPL`. Got the error:

> field type 'cv::ml::ANN_MLP' is an abstract class

Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just as an example and if you are importing the usual imports as mentioned:

```
using namespace cv;
using namespace ml;
using namespace std;


Ptr<ANN_MLP> mlp = ANN_MLP::create();

Mat layersSize = Mat(3, 1, CV_16U);
layersSize.row(0) = Scalar(inputTrainingData.cols);
layersSize.row(1) = Scalar(hiddenLayerSize);
layersSize.row(2) = Scalar(outputTrainingData.cols);
mlp->setLayerSizes(layersSize);

mlp->setActivationFunction(ANN_MLP::ActivationFunctions::SIGMOID_SYM);

TermCriteria termCrit = TermCriteria(
    TermCriteria::Type::COUNT + TermCriteria::Type::EPS,
    100000000,
    0.000000000000000001
);
mlp->setTermCriteria(termCrit);

mlp->setTrainMethod(ANN_MLP::TrainingMethods::BACKPROP);

Ptr<TrainData> trainingData = TrainData::create(
    inputTrainingData,
    SampleTypes::ROW_SAMPLE,
    outputTrainingData
);

mlp->train(trainingData);
```

You might want to look at the [official docs](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0.0/d0/dce/classcv_1_1ml_1_1ANN__MLP.html#details) for more details.

Answer (score -1):

Was converting some opencv2 code came across this, this may help

```
#include<opencv2/ml.hpp>

Ptr<ml::ANN_MLP> ann = ml::ANN_MLP::create();
Mat layers(1,3,CV_32SC1);
layers.at<int>(0)= TrainData.cols;
layers.at<int>(1)= nlayers;
layers.at<int>(2)= numCharacters;
ann->setActivationFunction(ml::ANN_MLP::SIGMOID_SYM, 1,1);
ann->setLayerSizes(layers);
```

the opencv 2 code was:

```
#include<ml.h>

CvANN_MLP  ann;
Mat layers(1,3,CV_32SC1);
layers.at<int>(0)= TrainData.cols;
layers.at<int>(1)= nlayers;
layers.at<int>(2)= numCharacters;
ann.create(layers, CvANN_MLP::SIGMOID_SYM, 1, 1);
```